# How to convert Java Maven Project to Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have an existing `Java Maven project`. Now I need to create `Maven Plugin` with the same functionality. How I can convert my existing project to `Maven Plugin`? Is there any step-by-step tutorial?

Comment: I think easiest way is create plugin project from archetype and move code after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called mojo: https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

(You should take care, that you use new guides with annotation)

Comment: Thank you. I created **Mojo**, and call my main jar from it.